# JQuery ejecuta varias veces evento click - Angular

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, typescript

estoy desarrollando una app con angular y un poco de JQuery y me he topado con un error.

El problema es que cuando llamo una función que esta en mi componente desde mi vista, está se ejecuta varias veces y yo simplemente le doy un solo click al botón.

Quisiera que alguien me ayudara con este problema.

Codigo  de mi vista (Donde llamo la función. La función se llama ¨update_contact()¨)

```
<div id="cotainer-contact">
<h2 class="head-style another-head">Contactos</h2>
<div id="search">
    <input (keydown.enter)="search_contact()" [(ngModel)]="text_search" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"  id="input-search" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre de Contacto">
    <div id="dos-botones">
        <button (click)="search_contact()" id="boton_search" class="btn btn-success boton_search">Buscar</button>
        <button (click)="show_contacts()" id="boton_all" class="btn btn-primary boton_search">Todos</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="card-container">
    <div *ngFor="let dato of this.listado_contactos; let i = index" class="card mt-5" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="image card-img-top img-fluid" src="../../assets//contact-icon-png-1.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title"><strong>Nombre:</strong> {{listado_contactos[i].NOMBRE}}</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title"><strong>Apellido:</strong> {{listado_contactos[i].APELLIDO}}</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title"><strong>Telefono:</strong> {{listado_contactos[i].TELEFONO}}</h5>
          <h5 class="card-title"><strong>Correo:</strong> {{listado_contactos[i].EMAIL}}</h5>
          <div id="botones">
            <button id="{{i}}" (click)="update_contact()" class="edit interactuar btn btn-primary editar">Editar</button>
            <button id="{{i}}" class="delete interactuar btn btn-danger borrar">Borrar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Código de mi componente (Donde se encuentra la función)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormComponent } from '../form/form.component';
import { ContactService } from "../Services/contact.service";
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

declare const $:any;

@Component({
selector: 'app-contacts',
templateUrl: './contacts.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./contacts.component.css'],
providers: [ContactService]
})
export class ContactsComponent {

public listado_contactos:string[];
public text_search:string;

constructor( private peticion?:ContactService ) {
    this.listado_contactos = []; 
}


//Metodo para actualizar un contacto
update_contact() {

    let aumentar = 0;

    $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(event) {
        const id = this.id;
        console.log(id);
    });
}
```

}

Como Pueden ver me imprime el id en la consola varias veces cuando solo le doy una sola vez al boton.

[image]

Comment: No necesitas usar jquery para manejar el click, ya lo estas administrando desde angular, lo que esta haciendo es que le das clic al boton, agrega un trigger para ejecutarse cuando le das de nuevo clic al boton y se esta duplicando el evento tantas veces como le das clic.

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es en update_contact, ya tienes el evento, ejecuta tu update, o la parte de tu código que vas a realizar en esa función

Comment: Muchas gracias. Uso JQuery para poder obtener el id del botón porque lo necesito. ¿Tienes alguna idea de cómo hacerlo con angular?

Answer (score 0):

Revisando tu código el problema que tienes es por que tu ya administras el evento clic en angular  y cada que entras a la función `update_contact` agregas un trigger para el evento clic, por tal motivo se esta duplicando el evento, y además no realiza nada en la primera iteración si no hasta las siguientes.

Lo que tienes que hacer es solo manejar el evento clic, y para obtener el valor de el ítem que das clic, puedes enviar el id de tu `data` como parámetro o el objeto entero.

Archivo Html

```HTML
  <div id="card-container">
      <div *ngFor="let dato of this.listado_contactos; let i = index" class="card mt-5" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img class="image card-img-top img-fluid" src="../../assets//contact-icon-png-1.png" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title"><strong>Nombre:</strong> {{dato.NOMBRE}}</h5>
            <h5 class="card-title"><strong>Apellido:</strong> {{dato.APELLIDO}}</h5>
            <h5 class="card-title"><strong>Telefono:</strong> {{dato.TELEFONO}}</h5>
            <h5 class="card-title"><strong>Correo:</strong> {{dato.EMAIL}}</h5>
            <div id="botones">
<!--Envo en update_contact un parametro dato, que es el que bindea dentro del ngfor -->
              <button id="edit_{{i}}" (click)="update_contact(dato)" class="edit interactuar btn btn-primary editar">Editar</button>
              <button id="delete_{{i}}" class="delete interactuar btn btn-danger borrar">Borrar</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Archivo ts

```js
//Metodo para actualizar un contacto
update_contact (dato) {
    console.log(dato);
}
```

Otras dos cosas que observe es que usas un ngFor para recorrer tu listado, pero al final usas el índice para acceder a tu lista, cuando ya la tienes en la variable data.

Y que declaras tu variable como un array de string, pero en realidad es un objeto.

Y que asignas el mismo id a tus dos botones.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Gracias por las observaciones, así lo haré.